# tkinter freezes regardless of threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have a button in tkinter toplevel and that triggers a function that utilizes multiprocessing on 4 core. Whenever the button pressed, the toplevel window will freeze and I've tried applying threading on the function, but it still freezes.

sample code:

```
def single_func(....):
# something intensive

def some_func(....):
    for i in something:
        p = Process(target = single_func, args = (....))
        p.start()
        p.join()

def run_prog():
    cancel.config(state = tk.DISABLED)
    thr = threading.Thread(target = some_func, args = (......))
    thr.start()
    thr.join()

run = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Yes", command = run_prog)
run.grid()
```

Any suggestions on this? I suspected that I need to define that tkinter gui and the function has to be declared explicitly to be on a different thread, but I'm not even sure.

Comment: Calling `join()` will block the application until the thread/process finish.

Comment: but not calling join() on run_prog() will make the program go passes through the process before finishing the function. I want to run the function without simultaneously making the window freeze

Comment: The process is running in the background.